# Microsoft.net\Framework\ folder is missing

Tags: .net-framework

I have an error with a .NET 4.0 ASP.NET application that requires me to run `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` from the .net frameowork directory. The problem is, it's missing. I have tried to download the .net 4.0 SDK but this installs to C:\Windows SDK\ and I have installed the main .net 4.0 redis package but am still missing it.

I am sure this is just the case of a bad installation or I am using the wrong download link but can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

You're downloading the wrong thing.

Try the [Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (Standalone Installer)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17718).

You can also try the smaller download of the [Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (Standalone Installer)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24872).